# MULE ESB and WMQ

Tags: jms, mule, esb

I imported a flow and clicked on the WMQ connector, and see the
following on the panel

```
Host name:      ${wmq.host}
Port:           ${wmq.port}
Queue Manager:  ${wmq.queue.manager}
Channel:
```

I have successfully gotten a WMQ connector working before, but I 
do not understand a couple of things

Where is ${wmq.host} and ${wmq.port} defined.

Where can I see their values.

Why isn't a channel defined, and yet this should be a tested and successful flow.

Answer (score 0):

Check in the project source code: you should find a `.properties` file that defines these values. It's most probably called `mule-app.properties`.